# Elasticsearch boosting with should not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to boost results that match the *should query* term by 10 but it's not working.

The mapping for keywords:

```
      "KEYWORDS" : {
        "type" : "text",
        "fields" : {
          "keyword" : {
            "type" : "text"
          }
        }
      },
```

And for animaltype:

```
      "animaltype" : {
        "type" : "text",
        "fields" : {
          "keyword" : {
            "type" : "text"
          }
        }
      },
```

When I index the data I make sure I index it as arrays.

Here is my query:

```
        GET /animals/_doc/_search
        {
        "query": {
            "bool":{
                "must":{
                    "terms": {  
                        "KEYWORDS.keyword": [ "catnip"]    
                            }   
                        },
                "should":{
                    "terms": {
                            "boost":10,
                                "animaltype.keyword": [ "cat"]
                                }  

                            }
                    }
                }
           }
```

When I run the query the max score is always 1.0
I need the terms that match the animaltyp "cat" to have a higher score.

What im I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong analyzer, hence the terms were in uppercase and I was using lowercase